# How to align container to body center?

Tags: html, css

I use following code:

```
<body>
<div style="width:450px; height:600px; align-self: center; background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
</body>
```

and get

[image]

I hope align green part to center, how to do it?

Comment: add `margin: 0 auto` in style

Comment: <html><head></head><body>
<div style="width:450px; height:600px; align-self: center; background-color: lightgreen;margin-left:35%;"></div>
</body></html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add in style:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```